# how to copy file to multiple sub directories linux

Tags: linux, copy

I have a file needs to copy unique directory call test 
directory structure as below

```
/contentroot/path/a/x/test
/contentroot/path/a/y/test
/contentroot/path/a/z/test
--------------------------
```

as above I have more then 250 combination test directory

I have try below command ( by using asterisk)  but it's only copy one test directly only  and giving issue (cp: omitting directory )

```
cp myfile.txt /contentroot/path/a/*/test
```

any Help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a for loop?

```sh
for FOLDER in /contentroot/path/a/*/test; do
    cp myfile.txt $FOLDER
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the output of an echo as an input to xargs. xargs will then run the cp command three times, appending the next directory path piped to it from the echo.

The -n 1 option on the xargs command is so it only appends one of those arguments at a time to the cp each time it runs.

```
echo /contentroot/path/a/x/test /contentroot/path/a/y/test /contentroot/path/a/z/test | xargs -n 1 cp myfile.txt
```

> Warnings! Firstly this will over-write files (if they exist) and secondlt any bash command should be tested and used at the runners risk! ;)

Comment: I have more then 250 combination test directory hence above can not use dude :(

Comment: Ah, that's a shame, although the principle might come in handy in the shell script it sounds like you need?